# How do frequentists estimate probabilities?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian

Say I have i.i.d. bernoulli trials $X_1, \cdots, X_n$. Now I observe $\sum_1^k X_i$ and want to estimate the probability that $\sum_k^n X_i \geq t$, where $t$ is some treshold.

I am used to Bayesian thinking. Therefore, no prior => no estimate. If I have a prior, I can simply use the Bayes theorem to do this. How do frequentists solve this kind of problems?

I could estimate $p$ as the sample average of the first $k$ random variables. However, I should also factor in the chance that this estimate is wrong. It is not clear how to do this in a formally correct way.

Now, I could estimate $P[\hat p\leq p−ϵ]$ using the Hoeffding bound as described by Michael, sure. But how can I say anything about the probability of $p$ being something? I mean, say $p$ is $1/2$. Then the first $k$ trials are irrelevant and the frequentist estimate is totally wrong. So maybe the *frequentist approach has some implicit assumptions which I don't understand* and which allow me to do these things?

Comment: You can estimate $p=P[X_1=1]$ quite well via $\hat{p}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^kX_i$.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: You may want to specify how you would compute $P[\sum_{i=k}^n X_i \geq t]$ if you knew $p$ exactly.  Likely you would use some approximation anyway. I observe that $P[\sum_{i=k}^n X_i \geq t]$ is nondecreasing in the $p$ parameter so it makes sense to look at $P[\hat{p}\leq p-\epsilon]$ and you can do this with the Chernov-Hoeffding bound.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description. I have figured this out, sorry for not writing it in the question. However, I don't see how I can say something about probabilities of $p$ being something without having a prior.

Comment: Chernov-Hoeffding does not need a prior: $$P[\hat{p}\leq p-\epsilon]\leq e^{-2k \epsilon^2}$$

Comment: But say $p = 1/2$. Then the approach you described would give a wrong answer if the estimate is, say $1/3$. Now, this is not likely but can happen and the answer will be wrong. Are there, therefore, some hidden assumptions I don't see?

Comment: Your answer will likely be "wrong" even if you knew $p=1/2$ exactly, as you will likely do some approximation for $P[\sum_{i=k+1}^{n} X_i>t]$ anyway (perhaps a central limit theorem approx?).  Your estimate $\hat{p}$ is unlikely to be dramatically far away from $p=1/2$, but there is always a chance you will be unlucky and see all-zeros for the first $k$ samples, you cannot do anything about that.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that thing with making frequentist estimates is that they only need to hold with high probability?

Comment: This seems like a question better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think the idea of frequentist estimation is that _if_ the true probability were above or below then estimate by a significant amount, there would have been a high prior probability that we would have gotten a different estimate. You never can actually say how likely it is that the estimate is accurate. At least that's my understanding of it, and initially this bothered me a lot.

Comment: is there a way to move?
@DavidK: Is there some way that makes this formal so that I can actually write proofs that are "formally correct"?

Comment: For any $p \in (0,1)$, neither a "Bayesian" nor a "frequentist" approach will *ever* recover the exact $p$ with complete confidence. A Bayesian approach can quantify the likelihood of the estimate with a posterior, and a frequentist approach can quantify it with estimates, such as the Chernoff bound Michael gave. This doesn't mean you only have statements "with high probability", but that you can bound the probability of deviating from the answer by any chosen amount.  In this sense you absolutely can "say how likely it is that the estimate is accurate."

Comment: You definitely cannot say how likely it is that an estimate that you have is accurate, as shown by my example. Perhaps what you meant is "say how likely an estimate that I will get is accurate"?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

Suppose $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli with unknown parameter $p \in [0,1]$, where $p=P[X_1=1]$. Suppose you want to estimate a value $f(p)$ for some function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$. Finally, suppose $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz so that 
$$ |f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y| \quad \forall x, y \in [0,1]$$
Then from $k$ samples $\{X_1, ..., X_k\}$ we can define 
$$ \hat{p}_k = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k X_i$$
Let our estimate be $f(\hat{p}_k)$.  Then for any $\epsilon>0$ we obtain: 
\begin{align*}
P[|f(p) - f(\hat{p}_k)|\geq \epsilon] &\overset{(a)}{\leq} P[L|p-\hat{p}_k|\geq \epsilon] \\
&\overset{(b)}{\leq} 2 e^{\frac{-2k\epsilon^2}{L^2}}
\end{align*}
where (a) holds by the Lipschitz property and (b) holds by the [Chernov-Hoeffding bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality).

Comment: You can apply this to the function $f(p)=\sum_{i \in \{t, ..., m\}} {m\choose i}p^i(1-p)^{m-i}$, with some extra work to find the Lipschitz parameter $L$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have expanded the answer with the explanation that I was missing up until now. Could you please check that it is correct?

Comment: @user2316602 : I received an external message that notified me of an edit to my answer. The edit was an extra paragraph that I did not write.  That edit was rolled-back (rejected) by an outside party.  I am thankful to that outside party because I am not comfortable with someone writing things in my own name. It is not good practice to add to someone else's answer. I think edits are only allowed so that "obvious" typos or formatting mistakes can be fixed.  If you want to add your own thoughts, you can do that in a comment or in a separate answer (you can answer your own question).